# How can I get Helium to work on my One?

Tags: backup, oneplus-one, helium

I'm trying to backup apps on my OnePlus One using [Helium](https://www.clockworkmod.com/carbon).

When I open the Helium Windows Desktop application, it works some magic and tells me Helium is now activated on my phone, but the app still shows a spinner and says it's waiting to be activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the thread [[How to] Helium Backup](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/how-to-helium-backup.253849/) by Bassick, one should use the [Helium Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/helium-backup/gpglbgbpeobllokpmeagpoagjbfknanl) to activate Helium. Then it will works just fine.